# Multiple function definitions with template haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Suppose I have a data type like so:

```
data Color = Red | Blue | Green
```

How would I generate a function like this using templatehaskell?

```
myShow Red   = ...
myShow Blue  = ...
myShow Green = ...
```

i.e. I'm looking for multiple definitions for a function based on pattern-matching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Test where 

import Language.Haskell.TH

data Color = Red | Blue | Green

myShow' :: Q [Dec]
myShow' = return [FunD (mkName "myShow") [mkClause 'Red, mkClause 'Blue, mkClause 'Green]]
  where mkClause n = Clause [ConP n []] (NormalB $ LitE $ StringL $ nameBase n) []
```

Comment: This put me on the right track. I ended up using a lambda with a case expression like so: `myShow = return $ LamE [VarP mc] (CaseE (VarE mc) $ [Match ...]
  where mc = mkName "mc"`